# Isotope - Responsive 4,3,2,1 layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope for a full width grid system. I've gotten it to work as I wish but am having some issues with the responsive element. I want to take a 4,3,2,1 approach to the system, eg. 4 items for desktop, 3 items for tablet, 2 items for mob landscape and 1 for mob portrait.

No matter what I try I am getting weird layouts when resizing. The closest I can get to it working is with the following code, but when resizing the window, sometimes elements drop onto a new line and cause huge gaps between the grid. I want the grid to be seamless.

This is my code:

```
<script>

        var $container = $('#isotope')
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $('#isotope').isotope({
                    // options
                    animationEngine : 'best-available',
                    layoutmode: 'masonry',
                    filter: '.all-header, .project, .clients, .news, .blog'
            });
        });
        // initialize Isotope
        $container.isotope({
                // options...
                resizable: true, // disable normal resizing
                // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
                masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 25 }
        });
        // update columnWidth on window resize
        $(window).smartresize(function(){
                $container.isotope({
                // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 25 }
                });
        });

        var $optionSets = $('#filter_bar .option-set'),
          $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

        $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
        }

        return false;
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to this which I've answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20270911/1010892

Hope that helps!